# Mod Rewrite .htaccess folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite my parameter from `www.example.com/admin/account?account=activity-log` to `www.example.com/admin/account/activity-log` and I don't know how to do that properly. Here's my current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]*)$ /admin/account.php?account=$1 [L]
```

That works well but that only gives me like this `www.example.com/account/activity-log`. I want to include the folder named `admin/`. I tried to add the admin folder before the `account/` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^admin/account/([^/]*)$ /admin/account.php?account=$1 [L]
```

but that only gives me 500 internal server error, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your code is in: [doc_root]/admin/.htaccess, then probably best to declare a rewritebase. Try this:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/
RewriteRule ^account/([^/]+)$ account.php?account=$1 [L]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.